# Why did the following code work instead of rename()?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to use `rename()` but it didn't work. I ended up using the following code. I want to understand these two lines and why it worked instead of `rename()`.

This code worked:

```py
df = df[['1999q4', 9926.1]]
df.columns = ['Quarter','GDP']
```

This code didn't work:

```py
df.rename(columns={"1999q4": "Quarter", 9926.1: "GDP"}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: I also tried using replace(), failed again.

Comment: both are not replaced? First should be reason month quarter period and second float precision, so `9926.1` is in real something like `9926.10000616367`.

Comment: Yes both are not replaced. However, i was trying to rename the column name only. The code that I provided worked perfectly. But I was looking for an explanation how it worked and why rename/replace didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving the code you shared and its working fine:
Say you have a dataframe like this (I added your columns as well):

```
`
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['yes', 'no', 'yes'], b': [10,  5, 20], "1999q4": [1, 2, 3], 9926.1: [2, 3, 4]})
df
`
```

Now if you do this part:

```
df = df[['1999q4', 9926.1]]
```

and then use the rename method:

```
df.rename(columns={"1999q4": "Quarter", 9926.1: "GDP"}, inplace = True)
df
```

it works fine!

Comment: you can check more about renaming columns here: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=macWY0n1VpM)